# Masstransit ConsumerCanceledException

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

Sometimes I got MassTransit.ConsumerCanceledException in my consumers.

> MT-Fault-ExceptionType:   MassTransit.ConsumerCanceledException 
> MT-Fault-Message:   The operation was canceled by the consumer

Why and when does Masstransit occur this exception? how can I resolve that? 
for testing, I wrote the below code. but I didn't get this exception. and the message was consumed without a problem.

```
public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext context)
      {
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10));
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ConsumerCanceledException` is thrown when a consumer throws an `OperationCanceledException` (or `TaskCanceledException` since it's a subclass). This represents a consumer-induced cancellation, vs. being canceled by MassTransit itself.

It's likely a method call in your consumer or dependency is throwing either of the above exceptions.